# Setting JTA Properties to an Atomikos + Spring Boot Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jta, atomikos

I'm trying to set an Atomikos JTA Property (e.g. com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout) in a Spring Boot Configuration, using the following:

```
import com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.transaction.TransactionManager;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionManagementConfiguration 
{

    @Bean(name="userTransactionServiceImp")
    public UserTransactionServiceImp userTransactionServiceImp()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout", "600000");
        UserTransactionServiceImp userTransactionServiceImp = new UserTransactionServiceImp(properties);
        return userTransactionServiceImp;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("userTransactionServiceImp")
    public UserTransaction userTransaction()
    {
        UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
        return userTransactionImp;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("userTransactionServiceImp")
    public TransactionManager userTransactionManager()
    {
        UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
        userTransactionManager.setStartupTransactionService(false);
        userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);
        return userTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        return new JtaTransactionManager(userTransaction(), userTransactionManager());
    }    

}
```

However, the property setting change to com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout is not picked up.

```
2015-09-23 14:31:33.810  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING core version: 3.9.3
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.automatic_resource_registration = true
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.client_demarcation = false
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.threaded_2pc = false
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.serial_jta_transactions = true
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.serializable_logging = true
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir = .\
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.max_actives = 50
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.checkpoint_interval = 500
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.enable_logging = true
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.output_dir = .\
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name = tmlog
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout = 300000
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.tm_unique_name = 127.0.0.1.tm
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING java.naming.factory.initial = com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING java.naming.provider.url = rmi://localhost:1099
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.service = com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.force_shutdown_on_vm_exit = false
2015-09-23 14:31:33.811  INFO 4748 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.a.i.c.i.AbstractUserTransactionService : USING com.atomikos.icatch.default_jta_timeout = 10000
```

I've read through the limited JTA Spring Boot materials (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html), search on Atomokis, etc. with no luck on what I might be doing wrong.

Have been using the following Atomikos Spring JTA documentation has a guideline for the Spring Boot configuration code:  http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/SpringIntegration#The_Advanced_Case_As_of_3_3

Any insight into this problem would be appreciated.

EDIT:  changing the @Bean initMethod/destroyMethod, and adding an @DependsOn to transactionManager() seems to have fixed the issued:

```
    @Bean(name="userTransactionServiceImp", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "shutdownForce")
    public UserTransactionServiceImp userTransactionServiceImp()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout", "3600000");
        UserTransactionServiceImp userTransactionServiceImp = new UserTransactionServiceImp(properties);
        return userTransactionServiceImp;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("userTransactionServiceImp")
    public UserTransaction userTransaction()
    {
        UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
        return userTransactionImp;
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    @DependsOn("userTransactionServiceImp")
    public TransactionManager userTransactionManager()
    {
        UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
        userTransactionManager.setStartupTransactionService(false);
        userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);
        return userTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("userTransactionServiceImp")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        return new JtaTransactionManager(userTransaction(), userTransactionManager());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According [Atomikos docs](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/JtaProperties#Transaction_manager), property `com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout` can be configured also via `UserTransaction.setTransactionTimeout()`.

Such configuration works for me (**notice this API is using value in seconds**):

```
  @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
  public UserTransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager()
      throws SystemException {
    UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager =
        new UserTransactionManager();
    userTransactionManager.setTransactionTimeout(600);
    return userTransactionManager;
  }

  @Bean
  public JtaTransactionManager transactionManager(
      UserTransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager) {
    JtaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setTransactionManager(atomikosTransactionManager);
    transactionManager.setUserTransaction(atomikosTransactionManager);
    return transactionManager;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, but change did not work for me.  My interpretation of the Atomikos docs referenced, is that UserTransaction.setTransactionTimeout() is limited by the max value of com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout, which is what I'm seeing (i.e. it's not an alternative to setting max_timeout).

Comment: @luboskrnac did you get any solution for that. using userTransactionManager.setTransactionTimeout(600) is not working for me too.... I have posted a question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282120/change-jta-transaction-timeout-from-default-to-custom

Answer (score 0):

@Configuration
public class AtomikosJtaConfiguration {

```
@Bean
public UserTransaction userTransaction() throws SystemException {
    UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp= new UserTransactionImp();
    userTransactionImp.setTransactionTimeout(1000);
    return userTransactionImp;
}

@Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
public TransactionManager transactionManager() {
    UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager= new UserTransactionManager();
    userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);
    return userTransactionManager;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Setting the JVM argument com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout as:

> -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout=3600000

worked for me.